# How to get minimum value from the SQL table?

Tags: sql

I have a table as below

```
ID   Date  
1    Null  
1    Null  
1    Null  
1    02/02/2012  
1    02/03/2012  
1    02/04/2012  
1    02/05/2012
```

I want to take a min date from the above table, that's result should be `Null`

I was trying to write

```
select min(date), Id from Table group by ID
```

then result is `02/02/2012`, but I want `Null`.

Is there any otherway to pull Null value from the above table except the below method?

```
select top 1 date, ID from table order by date asc
```

Comment: `select id from ztable where zdate is null`. NULL is not a value, so you cannot compare it to anything.

Comment: uhm so with min it's not impossible, you should test if table contains null, if contains min will automatic null in your case.

Comment: @wildplasser, Am looking for dynamic way. So is Min(date) don't pull the null value from the above table?

Comment: @Bigining.net NULL is not a value - it means "undefined" in SQL terms. As such, it can not be used in MIN.

Comment: MIN(xxx) implies a value, so NULL values are ignored on MIN(). ORDER BY is a bit different, cause it orders result rows, not values.

Comment: @Bigining.net: So you want the minimum unless there is one or more Nulls, where in that case, you want `NULL` returned?

Comment: to be honest, `select top 1` is the best way to go.

Comment: @Hans - Then you didn't read `GROUP BY id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the functions MAX and MIN do not count NULL in their evaluation of your data.

Try in this way, should do the trick :

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN MIN(COALESCE(Date, '19001231')) = '19001231' THEN NULL ELSE MIN(Date) END AS Date,
Id 
FROM X 
group by ID
```

Comment: Sorry, you are right, i have adapted the query from the Max case... Now it works

Comment: I've removed my down vote as it has the right ideas, however it is generally advisable to use the date format yyyyMMdd for hard coding dates. The reason being this is a culture insensitive date format and can't cause conversion errors like achieved [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc2a4/12)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your dbms is SQL-Server.

If you want to group by `id` but select all fields anyway, you can use a `cte` with `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT x.*
  , RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By id Order By date)
  FROM Table x
)
SELECT * FROM cte 
WHERE RN=1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc2a4/7

Comment: +1 from me, though I still think the OP should consider reforming the data/design to avoid needing this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of them are given the answer. but the final result working with below query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN   MIN(coalesce(date, '1900-01-01')) = '1900-01-01' THEN NULL ELSE MIN(date) END AS Date, ID
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a simple check for 'NULL'.  I didn't return an "ID" in the example since the "ID" seems meaningless in the example schema/query given.

```
    IF (EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM x WHERE date IS NULL)) SELECT NULL AS MinDate
    ELSE SELECT MIN(date) AS MinDate FROM x;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5fca/11